# C# Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent) not working properly?

Tags: c#, graphics, transparency

I'm drawing some graphics on a control area repeatedly, and each time I want to start fresh with a transparent background. So I use:

```
Graphics graph = control.CreateGraphics();
graph.Clear(Color.Transparent);
```

However, the graphics area seems to turn black instead of transparent. Any ideas?

Comment: The graphics functions like Clear are essentially no-ops when used with `Color.Transparent`. `graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent)` doesn't mean "make it such that my entire graphics space is transparent". Rather, it means, "clear my entire graphics space by painting the color 'Transparent' over my current space".

Comment: To diagnose why it's going black, we may need more info. Is this in a custom control in the Paint event handler? Are you setting any ControlStyles?

Comment: And do your paining in an `OnPaint` override...avoid `CreateGraphics`...it's evil.

Comment: It worked!  You see the back of the LCD monitor.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: This is done in a timer tick event (I'm drawing a new graph every second), so I'm not sure how I could place the code in the Paint event.

Comment: @MichaelGunter: The control is a plain picture control on a form.

Comment: The tick simply sets the table and calls for a refresh...the Paint method does the rendering.

Answer (score 8):

I found an alternate way to achieve what I need. I create a new transparent bitmap with the control's dimensions, draw my stuff on it and then use it as a background image for the control:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    bitmap.MakeTransparent();
    Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    //  draw stuff here ...

    control.BackgroundImage = bitmap;
    graph.Dispose();
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: It is better if your working with using statement for creating objects, which implement IDisposable Interface. The great benefit of this is, that you don't have to manage the disposal of your objects. 
So for cleaner implementation change
 Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
to
 using( Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap) )
{
    //  draw stuff here ...

    control.BackgroundImage = bitmap;
}

Comment: In my case, I also need to do `graph.Clear(Color.Transparent);` to make it works. But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

because picturebox has not transparency layer. you could be use transfer bitmap.
try this.

```
        tmp_bmp = new Bitmap(picturebox1.Width, picturebox1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
         Graphics Canvas = Graphics.FromImage(tmp_bmp);
         picturebox1.Image = tmp_Type;

        Type_Canvas.Clear(Color.Transparent);
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked fine for me:

```
private void MyCustomControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear background - also works when backcolor is transparent
        InvokePaintBackground(this, e);
```